# How can I use only one variables file from several variable files using webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to build my project for several themese. The bellow variables are the only changes in these themes. SO I have created several files with these variables and have assigned different values.

```
// colors
$primary-color: #306A48;
$dark-blue-1: #0f212f;
$dark-blue-2: #fff;
$dark-blue-3: #314252;
$dark-blue-4: #485661;
$gray-1: #72828f;
$gray-2: #97a5b1;
$gray-3: #afc0d0;
$gray-4: #afc0d0;
$yellow: #F2C94C;
$red-1: #EB5757;
$green-2: #27AE60;
$green-3: #6FCF97;
$red: #EB5757;

// media points
$breakpoint-xxl: 1400px;
$breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
$breakpoint-lg: 992px;
$breakpoint-md: 768px;
$breakpoint-sm: 576px;
$breakpoint-min: 360px;
```

The way i am trying to do is create several build scripts and from each script is should run different webpack rule. for that I should only import the relavent variable file. How can I do that ????

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple webpack config files and run a build script using a different file for each build.

Then in webpack config you specify a custom resolver

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      pathBeingImported: actualPathToASpecificFile,
    },
  },
}
```

Since it's a javascript file, you can alter the values within the alias based on process env and possibly not have to define multiple files.